# How D3.JS positions the <g>?

Tags: d3.js

I am really new to D3 and i m trying to understand how the the `<g>` are positioned in the svg.

Take the following example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-packed-bubble-chart?file=src%2Fapp%2Fd3-packed-bubble-chart.service.ts

How would be possible to approach the 2 clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `g` elements are positioned in lines 73-75 by setting the `g` elements' [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) attribute to `"translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"` via the the accessor function.

Essentially, applying a `translate(x,y)` value to a `transform` attribute on an element, means shifting the element `x` pixels horizontally and `y` pixels vertically.

Check out the documentation for the [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) attribute and what it does with a [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Translate) value.

The values of `d.x` and `d.y` are computed using D3's [pack](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#pack) and [hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#hierarchy) functions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. In this case, how woul be possible to approch the 2 datasets/clusters?

Comment: What do you mean by approach? There is one `g` element per circle, containing a `circle`, a `title`, and two `text` elements. The two clusters aren't divided into groups in your example.

Comment: So why do they get separated?

Comment: Because the dataset is divided into two groups. This makes the D3's pack function - https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy#pack - cluster them together in corresponding groups.

Comment: For your specific case, if you want to select all `g`elements from one of the clusters, you can change line 72 to this: `.attr("class", (d) => { return "node " + d.parent.data.name })`, thus adding either `ABC` or `CDE` as a class name to each `g`. Then you can afterwards select the corresponding cluster by a class selector - e.g.: `d3.selectAll('.ABC')`.

Comment: But we are really getting off topic from your original question about how you position `g` elements with D3.